# is this a Valid approach for SCD type2 implementation in spark without using delta lake?

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, hive, scd

### Approach:

Assuming there are 2 DataFrames daily and target with same columns, target DataFrame is also having previously expired records.

```
target=spark.read.table('target_db.target_table')

active=target.filter(col('record_Status')=='active')\
                       .withColumn('check_update_keys',
                                    concat(col('col1'),col('col2'),col('col3')))

expired=target.filter(col('record_Status')=='expired')

new_records=daily.join(active.select('check_update_keys'),how='left_anti',on=['check_update_keys'])\
                 .withColumn('record_status',lit('active'))

old_records=active.join(daily.select('check_update_keys'),how='left_anti',on=['check_update_keys'])\
                 .withColumn('record_status',lit('expired'))

common_records=active.join(daily.select('check_update_keys'),how='inner',on=['check_update_keys'])

final_df=common_records.union(new_records).union(old_records)\
                       .drop('check_update_keys')\
                       .union(expired)
```

### limitation:

One cannot read and overwrite the same table so first we need to write the data to new table in hive and then read and overwrite the target table in hive with partition on record status.

```
   final_df.coalesce(10).write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('staging_db.staging_table')
   final_df=spark.read.table('staging_db.staging_table')
   final_df.coalesce(10).write.partitionBy('record_status')\
           .mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('target_db.target_table')
```

Comment: "One cannot read and overwrite the same table... " - in hive it is possible to read and write the same table.

Comment: "OVERWRITE operation is what i am intending to do from spark"                                              I am taking about spark here, if you are reading the data in one dataframe and writing the data to same table in overwrite mode spark won't allow you to do it.